# NULL gets populated in table instead of values

Tags: mysql

When the following mysql query is executed,fields get populated with null instead of the value specified.

```
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES( 
slNo='2', mrp='3', PplusT='3.375', 
name='Eraser', code='002', qty='15', 
unitPrice='3', rateOfTax='12.5', taxAmt='0.375',
cess='0.004', total='50.625', billNo='10001')
```

The table schema

```
slNo            int(11)                                     
mrp             float                                           
PplusT          float                                       
name            varchar(50)                          
code            varchar(10)                          
qty             int(11)                 
unitPrice       float                   
rateOfTax       float                   
taxAmt          float                           
cess            float                       
total           float           
billNo          varchar(10)
```

I tried the query using PHP as well as PHPMYADMIN but the result is same.

Comment: Why downvote? The question is clear, concise, on topic, and even shows effort. I don't think it's fair to downvote simply because the OP doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). Replace `VALUES` with `SET`

```
INSERT INTO invoices
SET slNo=2, mrp=3, PplusT=3.375, 
name='Eraser', code='002', qty=15, 
unitPrice=3, rateOfTax=12.5, taxAmt=0.375,
cess=0.004, total=50.625, billNo='10001'
```

You must remove the quotes from the values for numeric data types, or it will try to insert them as strings.

Comment: Thanks:)I would never have found this myself :)

Comment: 10 more to go... doesn't mean 10 more intelligent characters

Comment: @Xaade Huh? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around the numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Try unquoting your numbers... you're essentially trying to insert strings into ints and floats

```
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES( 
slNo=2, mrp=3, PplusT=3.375, 
name='Eraser', code='002', qty=15, 
unitPrice=3, rateOfTax=12.5, taxAmt=0.375,
cess=0.004, total=50.625, billNo='10001')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

```
       INSERT INTO invoices SET 
           slNo='2', mrp='3', PplusT='3.375', 
           name='Eraser', code='002', qty='15', 
           unitPrice='3', rateOfTax='12.5', taxAmt='0.375',
           cess='0.004', total='50.625', billNo='10001'
```

or

```
   INSERT INTO invoices ( slNo, mrp, PplusT, name, code, qty, unitPrice, rateOfTax,taxAmt,
       cess, total, billNo) VALUES( '2', '3', '3.375', 'Eraser', '002', '15', '3', '12.5', '0.375','0.004', '50.625', '10001')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but an insert statement is not supposed to look like that:

```
INSERT INTO invoices (slNo, mrp, PplusT, name, code, qty, unitPrice, rateOfTax, taxAmt, cess, total, billNo) 
VALUES('2', '3', '3.375', 'Eraser', '002', '15', '3', '12.5', '0.375',
'0.004', '50.625', '10001')
```

Comment: I didn't think so either.. but check the manual on my answer. It is okay^^

Comment: @Shredder ah yes, I've seen that one. The `SET` for inserts was introduced since 5.0 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the format you have, and read this page. Also, it is not advised to surround integer values in quotes, I think it works in MySQL though...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)